# Type Erasure in Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

What does the following code look at runtime after type erasure:

```
public class Test<T> {

T lst;
List<T> list1;
void meth() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{  T res = (T)lst.getClass().newInstance();}

static <S> void meth(S t){}
}  
class TestUse{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Test<Integer> gint = new Test<Integer>();
Test<String> gstr = new Test<String>();
gint.meth();
gstr.meth();

}
```

Comment: you haven't defined `Genrics` class.

Comment: After type erasure `Genrics<Integer> gint = new Genrics<Integer>();
` will look like `Genrics gint = new Genrics();
`.

Comment: It doesn't 'look like' anything at runtime, because it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code would not work:

```
T res = (T)lst.getClass().newInstance();
```

Since T is of type Object at runtime in all the possible cases.

One workaround is using generics with inheritance:

```
public abstract class Generic<T> {

    public abstract Class<T> getConcreteClass();

    public void doSomething() {
        Class<T> clazz = getConcreteClass();
        T t = clazz.newInstance();
        doSomethingWithT();
    }
}

public class ConcreteClass extends Generic<YourObject> {
    public Class<YourObject> getConcreteClass() {
        return YourObject.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1649415: You haven't instantiated lst; it should throw a NullPointerException when calling getClass().

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Genrics` class is actually your `Test` class, it should be equivalent to something like this:

```
public class Genrics {

    Object lst;
    List list1;
    void meth() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Object res = lst.getClass().newInstance();
    }

    static void meth(Object t){}
}  
class TestUse{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Genrics gint = new Genrics();
        Genrics gstr = new Genrics();
        gint.meth();
        gstr.meth();
}
```

Whether my assumption is right or wrong, the way to think about this is that all generic type parameters are simply erased from your code and replaced with the most specific bound for the type parameter (`Object` in your case) or nothing where appropriate. Casts are introduced where needed.

The details of how type erasure works are spelled out in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6).

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like this

```
public class Test {

    Object lst;
    List list1;
    void meth() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{  
        Object res =lst.getCla ss().newInstance();
    }

   static void meth(Object t){
   }
}

class TestUse{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Genrics gint = new Genrics();
        Genrics gstr = new Genrics();
        gint.meth();
        gstr.meth();
    }
```

although I do not think this would compile as it stands. There is no Genrics class - or is that the Test class.

Comment: The `Test` class has a no-param `meth()` instance method.